# wordpress sprintf PHP error

Tags: php, wordpress, printf

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments in
>   /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/surveys/wpframe.php on
>   line 53

the code reads...

```
if(!function_exists('t')) {
/// Globalization function - Returns the transilated string
function t($message) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return __(call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args), $GLOBALS['wpframe_plugin_name']);
}
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Something that calls that function in the 'surveys' plugin is doing it *incorrectly*. I find the Wordpress plugins to be spotty. I'm always adding error checking. In general, turn off errors when running Wordpress in production.

Comment: I'd like to know more about this "turn off errors when running Wordpress in production" business.  Is this simple to do?

Comment: In php.ini set display_errors = Off and error_reporting to something I don't remember off hand. The comments in the file explain. Also make sure the wp-config.php has WP_DEBUG = false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sprintf requires at least 2 arguments: A format string, and a list of values to insert into that format string. e.g

```
sprintf('This is a %d decimal and this is a %s string', 42, 'xxx');
```

2 format characters, so requires 2 values to fill in. For every format character in the format string, you must have a matching value specified.

What's in your `$args` variable at the point you receive the error?

Comment: I've updated my question to include more of the code surrounding line 53.  I'm terribly sorry, but PHP is not my strong suite, and I'm not sure how to find what you've asked...

Comment: ok. Do a `var_dump($args)` just before that call_user_func business, which'll dump out the contents of $args in a readable format.

Comment: had a friend go over this with  me and we worked it out.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Any details on the solution?